# How to create a listview through xaml page in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am planning to create a list view in xamarin forms through xaml syntax, with listview having multiple columns custom data bindings. Can you please suggest some tutorial as I am unable to achieve this task.

Answer (score 3):

It's all explained here: [ListView Xamarin Guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/)

I suggest you look around Xamarin Guides, it has many useful tutorials :)